# Maximal normal $\pi$-subgroups and torsion subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let be $\mathbb{R}$ the real numbers and $\mathbb{Z}$ the integers. Let $G = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Determine

1. $O_\pi(G)$ - the normal maximal $\pi$-group of $G$,
2. $T(G)$ - torsion subgroup.

Comment: I know that $G$ is isomorphic to $\{x \in \mathbb{C} ; \mid \mid x \mid \mid = 1\}$. But, how use this for solving to the question?

Comment: This question is easier without using that isomorphism.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I did not understand. Using the isomorphism that exists between these two groups for these subgroups?

Answer (score 7):

Try using the definitions. We don't use anything special. At each step, we try to make the definition less fancy; we try to write things down in a way we understood earlier in life.

An element of $G=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a coset $r+\mathbb{Z}$. What does it mean for $r+\mathbb{Z}$ to be in $T(G)$?

It means $r+\mathbb{Z}$ has order $n$ for some positive integer $n \in \{1,2,\ldots\}$. Well what does that mean?

It means $n(r+\mathbb{Z}) = 0 + \mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \in \{1,2,\ldots\}$. What does this mean?

It means $nr-0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. What does that mean?

It means $nr=m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. What does that mean?

It means $r=\frac{m}{n}$. What does that mean?

It means $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. What does that tell us?

Oh, $T(G) = \{ r + \mathbb{Z} : r \in \mathbb{Q} \} =\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

The elements of order dividing $n$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are just the fractions $\tfrac{a}{n} + \mathbb{Z}$.

What elements live a $\pi$-group? Oh, the elements  $\tfrac{a}{n} + \mathbb{Z}$ where $n$ is a $\pi$-number.

Comment: Jack, I like your staccato style :-)!

Comment: @JackSchmidt Aside from the fact that you are arrogant, costing help those who know less? Moreover, for all his cockiness, you have not looked at how to get the $O_\pi(G)$. In any case, thank you and you have no time to help not access site that accepts beginners as its members.

Comment: @AgenorAndrade: I think you misread. This answer is not meant to insult anyone. Each step is meant to say, “what does the definition really say?” Before the last step ($T(G)=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$), all we do is take something fancy, and make it simpler and more common. The last step requires us to step back: what have we done? We have shown that $T(G) = \{ r + \mathbb{Z} : r \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, but that is just $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Let me know if you want the $\pi$-version explained, but there is only one difference. If $\pi$ is finite then you can write down the answer very nicely, $\mathbb{Z}[1/\prod \pi]/\mathbb{Z}$ (isn't $\prod \pi$ a funny expression?).